# How to get an SqlUTCTime in Haskell HDBC?

Tags: haskell, hdbc

I have a MariaDB database which I query through Haskell HDBC. In it I store a `datetime` column in UTC time. I would like to retrieve the values as `SqlUTCTime` and perform the conversion to `UTCTime` using `fromSql`.

- If I retrieve the values directly in `SELECT`, I get an `SqlLocalTime` which can not be converted to `UTCTime` by `fromSql`.
- If I try to use `DATE_FORMAT()` in SQL to get ISO8601 compliant strings (adding trailing `+00:00` or `Z` to indicate UTC), I get errors that the strings are not compliant.

I ultimately managed to convert manually from `SqlLocalTime` to `SqlUTCTime` :

```
convertSqlValue :: SqlValue -> Maybe UTCTime
convertSqlValue sql = case sql of
    SqlString s -> iso8601ParseM s
    SqlUTCTime u -> Just u
    SqlLocalTime l -> Just $ localTimeToUTC utc l
    other -> Nothing
```

where the `SqlLocalTime` is called and `localTimeToUTC utc l` performs the conversion.

My question therefore is: what should I do to get an `SqlUTCTime` directly ?

Comment: The documentation indicates that `SqlUTCTime` is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. Perhaps you could try using `DATE_FORMAT` to produce that, rather than an 8601-compliant string, and see what happens.

Comment: DATE_FORMAT(cards.last_valid, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') is not recognized as a SqlUTCTime.